# Why does Java need to copy heap memory from(to) direct memory when involving IO system call?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, directmemory

Why does Java need to copy heap memory from(to) direct memory when involving IO system call?

Some articles say that's because of the GC, but I don't understand it clearly. And if it's truly because of the GC, do other languages have this problem, such as Go or Python?

Comment: Where have you seen that claim? And what do you mean by "direct memory"?

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/j-zerocopy/) will help you understand the topic better.

Comment: I'm not JVM guy but isn't it because for years there was no general concept of objects' *pinning* in JVM? So typically their data must be copied to be safely used by the native code, not aware of compacting GC? I think Shenandoah does it better. [Here's a nice summary](https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/9-jni-critical-gclocker/).